# Unable to make accessoryview work on device, but OK in simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, key-value-coding

I have a table view with two dynamic prototype cells.  The tableview is shown using `performSegue` which does a modal display of a new Navigation controller.  It works fine on the IOS 6.0 simulator, but not on an IOS 5.1 device (I'm using the 6.0 SDK but targeting a 5.1 platform).

I can't get the accessory view to work correctly - two problems

1. If I add the disclosure accessory view to the dynamic table cell prototype and use the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` tableview delegate method, it never gets called.  This has been asked elsewhere but no answers yet.
2. Alternatively, if I use the storyboard editor to trigger a segue from the disclsoure accessory view, it works fine on the simulator, but crashes on the device when I attempt to dequeue the reusable cell.  Crash stackdump below

   ```
   2012-10-15 21:09:07.744 mainapp[338:707] CRASH: [<DateCell 0x1e5b30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key accessoryActionSegueTemplate.

   2012-10-15 21:09:07.771 mainapp[338:707] Stack Trace: (
   0   CoreFoundation                      0x373cd8a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186
   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x350d2259 objc_exception_throw + 32
   2   CoreFoundation                      0x373cd5c5 -[NSException init] + 0
   3   Foundation                          0x37bcc323 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 130
   4   Foundation                          0x37bcbe23 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 23
   5   UIKit                               0x31263965 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 156
   6   Foundation                          0x37ba5f09 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 132
   7   CoreFoundation                      0x3732c7d3 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 38
   8   CoreFoundation                      0x3732d461 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 152
   9   UIKit                               0x313190c3 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 918
   10  UIKit                               0x311027bd -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:] + 304
   11  mainapp                             0x0005b769 -[SetupViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 80
   12  UIKit                               0x31101efb -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 546
   13  UIKit                               0x31100fd9 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1076
   14  UIKit                               0x31100763 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 206
   15  UIKit                               0x310a4f15 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 148
   16  CoreFoundation                      0x3732c1fb -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 42
   17  QuartzCore                          0x374f1aa5 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 216
   18  QuartzCore                          0x374f16bd _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 216
   19  QuartzCore                          0x374f5843 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 226
   20  QuartzCore                          0x374f557f _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 314
   21  QuartzCore                          0x374ed4b9 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 56
   22  CoreFoundation                      0x373a1b1b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
   23  CoreFoundation                      0x3739fd57 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 258
   24  CoreFoundation                      0x373a00b1 __CFRunLoopRun + 760
   25  CoreFoundation                      0x373234a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
   26  CoreFoundation                      0x3732336d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
   27  GraphicsServices                    0x33ae2439 GSEventRunModal + 136
   28  UIKit                               0x310cfcd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
   29  mainapp                             0x000566ad main + 96
   30  mainapp                             0x00056648 start + 4
   )
   ```

I have tried deleting and recreating the scenes in storyboard thinking that they may have become corrupted, but no joy.  Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I get the error

```
    this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
```

It means that something is not hooked up right in the storyboard.

For example, a previously used property name is still hooked up to an element in the storyboard.

A workaround to this would be to make the segue from controller to controller in storyboard (zoomed out so it's not hooked up to a specific event) and implement:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Check for what cell is being selected and use

```
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];
```

Hope it helps, good luck.